# How can I use one internet connection in perl

Tags: perl

I have 2 internet connection wlan0 and eth0 and I want to run this script in wlan0 only.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( timeout => 1 );
$ua->agent("007");
my $req = HTTP::Request->new( GET => 'http://120.28.53.178/favicon.ico' ); # HTTP::Request in wlan0 connection
my $ok = 1;
my $res;
for ( 1 .. 10 ) {
    $res = $ua->request($req);
    if ( $res->is_success ) {
        print "+ Google is up\n";
    }
    else {
        print "- Google is down\n";
        $ok = 0;
        last;
    }
    sleep 1;
}
if ($ok) {
    print "Result: Google is OK!\n";
}
else {
    print "Result: Google is not OK!\n";
}
```

How can I code it to use wlan0 internet only. This is posible in perl script?

Comment: It isn't a perl task because OS selects the interface to perform a connection. Try to add a host route, for Linux is: `sudo route add -host 120.28.53.178 gw <GATEWAY> dev wlan0` where is `<GATEWAY>` is IP address of the default gateway at wlan0 interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this hack

```
@LWP::Protocol::http::EXTRA_SOCK_OPTS = (LocalAddr => $source_ip);
```

Comment: IP assigned to your WLAN connection.

Comment: Gateway: 192.168.0.1 or IP Address: 192.168.0.100